# How can I right align a text wrapped sentence next to an icon?

Tags: css, text

I am trying align a long string (text wrapped) to the right of an icon.

Here is my CSS:

```
  :root {
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;

    .icon-button-size {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  }
```

and here is my HTML:

```
  <ion-card>
      <ion-list>
        <div>
          <span class="icon-button-frame">
              <ion-icon class="icon-button-size" color="primary" [name]="lr.likelyRank === selectedLikely?'checkmark-circle':'stop-circle'"></ion-icon>
              {{lr.likelyName}}
          </span>
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let likely of lr.likelyCriteria">{{likely}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-card>
```

and below is the actual screenshot.

[image: How do I make the text be wrapped neatly to the left of the green icon?]

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you. I have added some CSS and made the container `flex`.

```css
.icon-button-frame {
  display: flex;
}

.icon-button-frame ion-icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="icon-button-frame">
              <ion-icon class="icon-button-size" color="primary" [name]="lr.likelyRank === selectedLikely?'checkmark-circle':'stop-circle'"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdic9.png" height="48" /></ion-icon>
Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text 
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this code like this,

```
<span class="icon-button-frame">
     <ion-icon class="icon-button-size" color="primary" [name]="lr.likelyRank === selectedLikely?'checkmark-circle':'stop-circle'"></ion-icon>
      <span class="likely-name">{{lr.likelyName}}</span>
</span>
```

As the above code, instead of outputting the likelyName next to the ion-icon, wrap it with the span tag so you can easily write css for the span to set width and text-align to make icon and text seperate.

If you set width for icon(for example: icon size 30*30) and set the below css for "likely-name" span tag

```
display: inline-block (or you can use)
float: left
min-width: 160px    // if you like to set minimum width.
```

this will ensure both icon and text element is separate so the text is wrap below the first line of text starts.

check this demo url of codepen https://codepen.io/Santhanakrishnan/pen/jOVOWEg

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit Sandy.  What would the extra entries be in the css for the desired width and text-align?

Comment: Sorry Sandy.  It still didn't work.  The text of "Almost Certain or Currently Occurring" is underneath the icon.

Comment: @DerekMegyesi check the above demo url to seperate the icon and text.

Comment: Sorry Sandy.  It is still not working.  The text is now aligned in the upper part of the icon. How can I make the text (wrapped and aligned) to the middle of the icon.

Comment: add veritical-align: middle or vertical-align: baseline; css property.